# Jolt for complex JSON transform

Tags: jolt

Extracting values from first array element and second element and joining both.
Input String:

```
[
  {
    "creationDate": "2020-04-01T14:14:32.685+0000",
    "factValues": [
      {
        "Factname": "Medicine",
        "factvalue": "1234556",
        "sourcePguid": "1"
      },
      {
        "Factname": "Journal",
        "factvalue": "123455",
        "sourcePguid": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "creationDate": "2020-04-01T14:14:32.685+0000",
    "factValues": [
      {
        "Factname": "chemical",
        "factvalue": "123455567",
        "sourcePguid": "2"
      },
      {
        "Factname": "Rubber",
        "factvalue": "123455435",
        "sourcePguid": "3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output excepted:

```
{
   {
    "sourcePguid" : "1",
    "Medicine":"1234556",
    "Journal":"123455"
  }, {
    "sourcePguid" : "2",
    "chemical":"123455567",
    "Rubber":"123455435"
  } 
}
```

Kindly help me to achieve the expected output.json in spec.json. The spec is not transforming as expected output. I want learn how to use attributes inside the string parser.It would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this might help,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "factValues": {
          "*": {
            "sourcePguid": "&3.sourcePguid",
            "@(0,factvalue)": "&3.@Factname"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "sourcePguid": "=firstElement(@(1,sourcePguid))"
      }
    }
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another answer using JSONata

> For java: https://github.com/IBM/JSONata4Java

```
$.factValues{
    sourcePguid: {
        "sourcePguid": $distinct(sourcePguid),
        Factname:factvalue
    }    
} ~> $each(function($v){$v})
```